# 今でも vs 今も in 1年前からも、今でも(も)、変われない自分が嫌い

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference in using でも and も
Example:

> 1年前からも、今でも、変われない自分が嫌い
> 1年前からも、今も、変われない自分が嫌い

They both probably mean "Ever since last time, and even now, I hate the me who can't change"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

今も and 今でも are almost completely interchangeable in your example. They are interchangeable in most other cases, too, but 今でも may have a stronger sense of "even" or "still". For example, お父様は今もお元気ですか is fine, but お父様は今でもお元気ですか may sound a little inconsiderate.